# Always show tooltip at the same position from containg dive

Tags: html, css, tooltip

When I hover over the first Div, the tooltip is shown further away than if I hover over the following two divs. Obviously it is because the text inside the div is larger/longer. But I don't want to show the tooltip span not depending on the hover text, but relating to the containing div of the text, so it is shown always at the same position.

jQuery is not an option for anything though but I kind of think, that it's a CSS problem anyway.

```css
.subPhaseContainer {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projectItem {
  margin: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 17px;
}

.projectItem.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.projectNumber {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}

.projectNumber .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.projectNumber .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}

.projectNumber:hover .tooltiptext.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.projectNumber:hover .tooltiptext.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.projectNumber:hover .tooltiptext.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="subPhaseContainer">
  <div class="projectItem green">
    <div class="projectNumber"><span>AAAA-00</span>
      <span class="tooltiptext green">Tooltip Sample</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projectItem green">
    <div class="projectNumber">
      <span>BBB-11</span>
      <span class="tooltiptext green">Tooltip Sample</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projectItem green">
    <div class="projectNumber">
      <span>CCC-22</span>
      <span class="tooltiptext green">Tooltip Sample</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify either a 'left' or 'right' position for your tooltiptext span, otherwise its left/right position will be the same as it would have been had you kept the tooltiptext span positioned relative.

So just update your CSS for the tooltiptext to this:

```
.projectNumber .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  top: -1px;
  right: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: man, so easy. thanks a lot! didnt think about that. all that because i m forced to do some front end. :)